# Azure streaming analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

This is more of an architecture question.

I’ve got a current architecture which sits like this

Azure http function -> service bus -> azure bus function -> database -> azure scheduled function -> analytics database

Now I’m wondering if I could simplify all this using azure streaming analytics with 2 sinks.

My main concern is doing validation. If a sink errors, then all sinks are retried. What happens if I get a poison message in the stream? It’ll kill my system?

My current system will retry and then dead letter

So I guess, my first question. How do you stop poison messages entering streaming analytics if always retry is enabled?

I’m thinking of modifying the http function to validate, then place the messages into event grid. What happens if the message changes? Eg, the validation rules? I’m guessing I need to keep it backwards compatible?

Comment: There's really no way to answer this objectively. I suggest editing to show what you've tried (along with sample data, Stream Analytics query, expected vs actual behavior, etc). This is too broad and open-ended (and opinion-based) as written. As for "how to build resilience into stream analytics" - again, really no single answer - I suggest starting with the docs to see how errors can be handled.

Comment: Uodated to be more specific